# Getting the right version of datacube-explorer

Tags: open-data-cube

How can I get the right version of datacube-explorer-2.5.4? Because a try to install this one https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-explorer/releases but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

That page does have the latest stable version.

Extract it to a directory, enter the directory, and `pip install .`

If you're seeing an older version after running those steps, perhaps try uninstalling any older installs first with `pip uninstall datacube-explorer`, and then try again with [the setup and run instructions](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-explorer#developer-setup). Pip may be skipping the install if you have an older dev version installed.